# Would like to display "To be contined" for all pages in report and for last report "End of report" has to be displayed using iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

I have designed an iReport where it should display all the records in the report. If a report has 2 pages for example then first page should display "To be continued" second page should display "End of the report" irrespective of number of pages you are working with.

I have placed a label at the footer of the report and changed the properties "print when expression" as

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($V{PAGE_COUNT}.toString()) ? "End of Report" : "Continue"
```

and displays error while executing the report

```
Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property that you should fill is `Text field expresion` and change by:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($V{PAGE_COUNT}) ? "End of Report" : "Continue"
```

because you are comparing Integers.

Your text field in the xml should be:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="xx" y="xx" width="xx" height="xx" uuid="xxxx"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="xxx" verticalAlignment="xxx">
        <font fontName="xx"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}.equals($V{PAGE_COUNT}) ? "End of Report" : "Continue"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: Any idea how to specify Text field expression

Comment: @Pallavi i have added the code to xml, but ireport designed has that property on the textfield elements.

Comment: Its working in iReport i should check this with bulk records in a page and test. Anyhow thanks

Comment: @Jilema when i took data to display in that respective report and try to use the same expression which you have shared, it is working differently like: I have 14 pages from 1st page to 11th page it is displaying to be continued and at 11th page it is displaying end of the report and for remaining pages it is displaying to be continued.  It is not working as expected