# How to add "Continued on next page..." text in the footer of each page except last?

Tags: jasper-reports

#### Requirement:

Add *"Continued on next page..."* text in the footer of each page except the last page in *Jasper report*. So basically i want to let the user know that there's more to view on the the next page of the report. I am aware of *page x of y* thing, which also let us know if there are more pages to see, but i want to make it more user friendly.

#### What i have done so far !!

1. Created a custom variable as below:

   ```
   <variable name="pNumber" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Page">
       <variableExpression><![CDATA[1]]></variableExpression>
       <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER} + 1]]></initialValueExpression>
   </variable>
   ```
2. Created the TextField in the footer as below:

   ```
   <textField evaluationTime="Auto">
           <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="15" backcolor="#D1CBCB" uuid="dd084b9e-66ab-494a-ad7d-0860be1796fb">
               <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
               <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
               <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>                  
           </reportElement>
           <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
               <font isBold="true"/>
           </textElement>
           <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Continued on next page..." + $V{pNumber} +"!="+ $V{PAGE_NUMBER} + " : "+ new Boolean(($V{pNumber}.equals($V{PAGE_NUMBER})) == false)]]></textFieldExpression>
       </textField>
   ```

Now, when i run the report which has total 3 pages, the TextField content shows the below text in each page as mentioned:

*First Page*: Continued on next page...1!=3 : true

*Second Page*: Continued on next page...2!=3 : true

*Third Page*: Continued on next page...3!=3 : false

*This expression works perfectly fine in the Text Field expression. Now, i want to use the same condition in Print When Expression of the TextField which will allow me to show the "Continue...text" if it returns true,or else nothing if false.*

#### But, if i use this condition in Print When Expression of the same TextField, the TextField just doesn't show in either situation(true/false). The expression is mentioned below :

```
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean(($V{pNumber}.equals($V{PAGE_NUMBER})) == false)]]></printWhenExpression>
```

I searched a lot on this issue, but didn't find any straight forward solution. Btw I am using *TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio 6.1.1 - Visual Designer - community edition for JasperReports*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would like to display "To be contined" for all pages in report and for last report "End of report" has to be displayed using iReport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125249/would-like-to-display-to-be-contined-for-all-pages-in-report-and-for-last-repo) & [Compare current page number with last page number](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5138360/876298)

Comment: Hi @AlexK , thanks for the comment. I checked the mentioned links.
1. First link uses Textfield expression to just change the text based on a condition. And that condition already works in my case also. but i want to use it in Print When Expression instead, which will totally hide the element itself if its not supposed to show on a page. So, I don't think this is for me.

2. The solution given by Mihir is incomplete i guess. No explanation. I also tried adding his expression in summay, but then the summary itself disappears :(

Comment: Have you tried Boolean.FALSE or Boolean.TRUE instead of false or true ? or remove your == false from your expression "new Boolean(($V{pNumber}.equals($V{PAGE_NUMBER})) == false".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of using it in Print When Expression is its `evaluationTime` that you can not change so you need hacks like [Compare current page number with last page number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138360/compare-current-page-number-with-last-page-number)

The true solution to this problem however is to use the `<lastPageFooter>` band, it was added to be able to have different content in last page footer, hence no need for expressions with hacks, just leave it without the `textField`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Petter Friberg. Using Page Footer and Last Page Footer simultaneously suggested by you solved my issue. This is very simple and straight forward solution to my problem. Thanks again :)